# Loop through multiple excel files and return a value

Tags: vba, excel

At this moment for the sake of simplicity I created just 3 excel files : Book1, Book2, Book3, each one with 2 columns. I looped through all excel files and populate all variables in my array, but I'm not able to display the values that I need in my Search excel file. One column is ***MyValue*** and the other column is a **Value** that i need to be shown in my Search excel file (the one with my macro). 
***MyValue*** can have multiple rows with the same value and I should take all the ***Values***(which are not the same) and display them.

```
Sub MyFunction()

Dim MyValue As String
Dim MyFolder As String 'Path containing the files for looping
Dim MyFile As String 'Filename obtained by Dir function

Dim Matrice() As Variant
Dim Dim1, Dim2 As Long

MyFolder = "E:\Excel Files\" 'Assign directory to MyFolder variable

MyFile = Dir(MyFolder) 'Dir gets the first file of the folder

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
MyValue = InputBox("Type the Value")

'Loop through all files until Dir cannot find anymore
Do While MyFile <> ""
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFolder & MyFile)
    'Sheets1.Activate
    Dim1 = Range("A2", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count - 1
    Dim2 = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Cells.Count - 1

    ReDim Matrice(0 To Dim1, 0 To Dim2)
    'The statements you want to run on each file
    For Dim1 = LBound(Matrice, 1) To UBound(Matrice, 1)
        For Dim2 = LBound(Matrice, 2) To UBound(Matrice, 2)

        Matrice(Dim1, Dim2) = Range("A2").Offset(Dim1, Dim2).Value
        If Matrice(Dim1, Dim2) = MyValue Then
            ThisWorkbook.Activate
            Range("A1", Range("A2").End(xlDown)) = Matrice(Dim1, Dim2 + 1)
            ' Values that i want to be displayed on column A in my Search.xlsm file
            ' is not displayed any value

        End If

        Next Dim2
    Next Dim1

    wbk.Close savechanges:=True
    MyFile = Dir 'Dir gets the next file in the folder

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: not sure I follow your code, `Range("A1", Range("A2").End(xlDown)) = Matrice(Dim1, Dim2 + 1)` are you trying to save the Matrice to a certain position in this workbook ?

Comment: yes. Search excel file is empty, so i try to put on column A what is I'm getting from the Values column

Comment: is the data allways on the same columns ? lets say column A and Column B? can you upload a sample of worksheet in _Book1_ ?

Comment: ok, i uploaded these files. I'm not allowed to upload the real files that i need to run these macros. here is the link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/16mcnq53y6wh4lb/AABbK2KOqVfC-1NAx2vHCu0ha?dl=0

Comment: see my answer below, let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I understood your post, the code below copies only ***Value*** data where Cells value (in **Column B**) = ***MyValue*** into the **Matrice() array**.

**Edit 1**: Removes the section taht removes all **Value** duplicates.

Copies all Values to **ThisWorkbook ("Sheet1")**.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MyFunction()

Dim MyValue As String
Dim MyFolder As String 'Path containing the files for looping
Dim MyFile As Variant 'Filename obtained by Dir function
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wSht As Worksheet

Dim Matrice()   As Variant
Dim Dim1, Dim2 As Long
Dim i, j As Long
Dim Matrice_size As Long

MyFolder = "\\EMEA.corning.com\ACGB-UD$\UD2\radoshits\My Documents\_Advanced Excel\SO Tests\" '  "E:\Excel Files\" 'Assign directory to MyFolder variable

MyFile = Dir(MyFolder) 'Dir gets the first file of the folder
MyValue = InputBox("Type the Value")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Matrice_size = 0
'Loop through all files until Dir cannot find anymore
' add only cells = MyValue to the Matrice array
Do While MyFile <> ""
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFolder & MyFile)
    Set wSht = wbk.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Sheets1.Activate
    Dim1 = wSht.Range("A2", wSht.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count - 1
    'Dim2 = wSht.Range("A1", wSht.Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Cells.Count - 1

    For i = 2 To Dim1
        If wSht.Cells(i, 1) = MyValue Then
            ReDim Preserve Matrice(0 To Matrice_size)
            Matrice(Matrice_size) = wSht.Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value
            Matrice_size = Matrice_size + 1
        End If
    Next i

    wbk.Close savechanges:=True
    MyFile = Dir 'Dir gets the next file in the folder
Loop

' copy the array to Sheet1 in this workbook, starting from Cell A2 >> can modify to your needs
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Resize(UBound(Matrice) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Matrice)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Way better,  but I don't need to remove any duplicates, for instance for MyValue=CELLID23 which is in Book1, I want to display all the values for this variable. in this case 123 and 132. Your code display only 123 value.

Comment: You want me to remove the sort? Or you wanna try it ?

Comment: i put a comment block for 'remove duplicates from array'  and I changed in the last statement Matrice_NoDup with Matrice, but nothing changes. When i Step Into Matrice and i look to Local Window for variable values i don't see Matrice populated with other value than 123 for CELLID23, even though it has other value in Book1.

Comment: still returns only the first value

Comment: @AndreiVieru it's working on the 3 demo files I have made. Are your source files sheets are named "Sheet1" ? are the values allways in Column A and Column B ? Do you have blank rows in the middle of your range ?

Comment: I had to change Dim1 = wSht.Range("A2", wSht.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count - 1 with +1. It didn't take the last two rows. Anyway Thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of `Filter` and `RemoveDuplicates`.

```
Sub ImportUniqueData()
    Const MyFolder = "E:\Excel Files\"
    Dim xlWB As Workbook
    Dim NextRow As Long
    Dim MyFile As String, MyValue As String
    Dim FilteredData As Range
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "*.xlsx")
    MyValue = InputBox("Type the Value")

    Do Until MyFile = ""
        NextRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        Set xlWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFolder & MyFile)

        With xlWB.Worksheets(1)
            .Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=MyValue
            Set FilteredData = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            FilteredData.Copy ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(NextRow, 1)
        End With

        xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=False

        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates
End Sub
```